# better way to load data for millions of users

Tags: design, data, efficiency, spring, mongodb

I am working on a Spring/JSF app in which i have 1 scheduler to load user's sleep activity from fitbit. Right now what i do is that whenever the scheduler kicks in, I load `ALL` users from `mongoDB` and for each user i send a request to *fitbit* api to fetch `sleep` activity and save it in `mongoDB` one by one.

As of now, its working fine however, once the user grows to million, this one scheduler could take sometime to execute. Not to mention, I am loading ALL users at once.

Right now what i am trying to research is (seeking help here if i am right track or not)

1. Group users someway and fetch user sleep group by group. Or i can use `pagination` here.
2. For each user, I can spawn a separate thread and let that thread finish independently without hogging the scheduler which is being called by spring container.

Am i on the right track or are there any better way to do so ? Also, right now, I am using only sleep activity, in future there will be more activities that i have to fetch from fitbit.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good use for a producer/consumer setup. Without going into the implementation in detail, you'd have one component whose job it is to pull the list of users from the DB and add them all to a queue. This could be triggered by your timer. Then, you'd have a component which sits there in a loop pulling an item from the queue, making the API request and saving the data. When you need to go faster you can just add more instances of that second component - so you still have a single producer (adding items to the queue) but multiple consumers (pulling from the queue and doing the work).

In terms of implementation there's a bunch of ways to do it - Java has a lot of support for such things, typically based around [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). If it were me I'd use [Akka](http://akka.io/), but that's a whole other question :)

Comment: Thanks. Shall i dump all of the users onto Queue at once ? Or shall i break it down. I mean how can i make it efficient to fetch millions of users from db ? Shall i do it in one query ? Break it down ?

Comment: That's a difficult question to answer without knowing a lot more about your situation. If it's literally millions of users then I would split it up just because putting that many objects in the queue would take a bunch of heap space. If, for example, you need to update each user once per day you could run your timer task multiple times pulling a different set of users (based on first character of their ID) each time. A lot of people would use something like RabbitMQ or Kafka to keep the queue outside of the JVM...would be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this :

The requirement is to find out the sleeping activity of the user ids that are stored in MongoDB which can grow till  1 Million. Later this requirement can be extended to pull other activities of the user.

To build a decoupled scalable system, you can create 2 services.

Service 1 : picks up the userIds from mongoDB or other datasources (if want to change it to something else tomorrow) and keep it in a Queue Service. I would suggest using a cloud-based Queue Service like SQS.

Service 2 : Picks up the data from a Queue and tries to contact 3rd party services like FitBit to get the activity. Let us say if Fitbit service is down/ or your service became quite popular and if there is a surge in the users you can increase the hosts that can consume the messages. You can use Auto-Scale feature of Amazon Webservices to take care of autoscaling.

Let's say tomorrow you want to fetch more activities of users from other systems like Google Fit to summarize all their fitness activities the same architecture works perfectly. The only change you need to do is to use a Simple Notification Service, instead of SQS which pushes the user ids into various SQS queues and each queue will be consumed by a different activity handler to process the data and updates your datastore.